Unwrapping multiple nested HTML elements with Cheerio
Given an HTML string with multiple nested elements, how can I remove all font elements using cheerio while maintaining the internal contents of the innermost font element?
For example this is the before
<body>
  <font>
    <font>
      <font>
        <p>Three fonts deep</p>
      </font>
    </font>
    <font>
      Two fonts deep
    </font>
  </font>
  <font>
    One font deep
  </font>
  No fonts deep  
</body>

and this is the after
<body>
  <p>Three fonts deep</p>
  Two fonts deep
  One font deep
  No fonts deep
</body>

I have tried the unwrap
$('font').each((i, el) => {
  $(el).unwrap();
});

and replaceWith
$('*').each((i, el) => {
  if (el.name === 'font') {
    $(el).replaceWith($(el).html());
  }
});

and both of these only remove the outer layer of font. I suspect that altering the HTML while in the each loop causes an issue?
If I run replacement in a while loop it does work.
let foundFonts;
do {
  foundFonts = 0;
  $('font').each((i, el) => {
    $(el).replaceWith($(el).html());
    foundFonts++;
  });
} while (foundFonts > 0);

I'm wondering, is there an efficient way to get rid of the font elements in a single pass?

Try iterating in reverse in your replaceWith attempt:
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // ^1.0.0-rc.12

const html = `<body>
  <font>
    <font>
      <font>
        <p>Three fonts deep</p>
      </font>
    </font>
    <font>
      Two fonts deep
    </font>
  </font>
  <font>
    One font deep
  </font>
  No fonts deep  
</body>`;

const $ = cheerio.load(html);

[...$("font")]
  .reverse()
  .forEach(el => $(el).replaceWith($(el).html()));

console.log($.html())

Output:
<html><head></head><body>
  
    
      
        <p>Three fonts deep</p>
      
    
    
      Two fonts deep
    
  
  
    One font deep
  
  No fonts deep  

</body></html>

Forward looping (root to leaf in the HTML tree) doesn't work because once you process the outermost <font>, its subtree becomes freshly-created and the elements inside of it are no longer part of the tree being looped over.
